# YII language selector doesn't make the postback to controller

Tags: php, yii

I'm making a language selector and followed [this](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/26/setting-and-maintaining-the-language-in-application-i18n/) wiki. I can implement the widget, but when I try the dropdown it doesn't make the postback. For the controller I have the idea that the controller should be: components/Controller.php in stead of components/MyController.php. But anyways both don't work. Does anyone know what to do here? I'm missing something about the essentials of catching a postback here i think..

Controller (components/controller.php):

```
    function init()
        {
            parent::init();
            $app = Yii::app();
            if (isset($_POST['_lang']))
            {
                $app->language = $_POST['_lang'];
                $app->session['_lang'] = $app->language;
            }
            else if (isset($app->session['_lang']))
            {
                $app->language = $app->session['_lang'];
            }
            Yii::app()->session['_lang'] = 'anders';
        }
```

widget class (components/LangBox.php):

```
class LangBox extends CWidget
{
    public function run()
    {
        $currentLang = Yii::app()->language;
        $this->render('langBox', array('currentLang' => $currentLang));
    }
}
```

widget view (components/views/langBox.php)

```
<?php echo CHtml::form(); ?>
    <div id="langdrop">
        <?php echo CHtml::dropDownList('_lang', $currentLang, array(
            'en_us' => 'English', 'is_is' => 'Icelandic'), array('submit' => '')); ?>
    </div>
<?php echo CHtml::endForm(); ?>
```

Comment: Do you see any POST requests on network tab of Chrome/Firefox developer tools? Did you extend your controllers from `Controller` (`components/controller.php`)?

Comment: Your code works for me. Can you describe in what way it's not working for you? What output are you expecting, and what are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

I am sure your code works ok, but are you actually submitting the form? You should really have a jquery that detects when the dropdown changed and submits it to the server and refreshes the page. Everything else is sound.

I have no idea what 'submit'=>'' does.